# cakephp cakeDC user redirect from login

Tags: cakephp

I am using cakeDC's user plugin and I am having an issue when using the routes.

When i go to my domain.com/login I get redirected to my domain.com/users/login with the flash message "You are not authorized to access that location."

**Routes.php**

```
CakePlugin::routes();
Router::connect('/users', array('plugin' => 'users', 'controller' => 'users'));
Router::connect('/users/index/*', array('plugin' => 'users', 'controller' => 'users'));
Router::connect('/users/:action/*', array('plugin' => 'users', 'controller' => 'users'));
Router::connect('/users/users/:action/*', array('plugin' => 'users', 'controller' => 'users'));
Router::connect('/login', array('plugin' => 'users', 'controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login'));
Router::connect('/logout', array('plugin' => 'users', 'controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'logout'));
Router::connect('/register', array('plugin' => 'users', 'controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'add'));
```

AppController.php

```
function beforeFilter() {
    parent::beforeFilter();
    //$this->Auth->allow('index');
    $this->set('logged_in', $this->Auth->loggedIn());
    $this->set('current_user', $this->Auth->user());
    $this->Auth->fields = array('username' => 'username', 'password' => 'passwd');
    $this->Auth->loginAction = array('plugin' => 'users', 'controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login', 'admin' => false);
    $this->Auth->loginRedirect = '/';
    $this->Auth->authError = __('Sorry, but you need to login to access this location.', true);
    $this->Auth->loginError = __('Invalid username / password combination.  Please try again', true);
    $this->Auth->autoRedirect = true;
    $this->Auth->userModel = 'User';
    $this->Auth->userScope = array('User.active' => 1);
    if ($this->Auth->user()) {
        $this->set('userData', $this->Auth->user());
    $this->set('isAuthorized', ($this->Auth->user('id') != ''));
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bellow line shouldn't be wrapped in the if statement:

```
$this->Auth->allow('login');
```

Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13687080/cakedc-users-login-with-username). It might help you.

Comment: Yes thanks, that was a typo. I had it outside the if statement. When I did I could get the /login but I did login I redirected to /users/login and got the message The request has been black-holed

Comment: So do you have that line somewhere in your beforeFilter method? I see you removed it from the if statement. Where is it now?

Comment: why I added it, I could log in the first time with /login but after that when I log in I get redirected to /user/login with an error "The request has been black-holed - Error: The requested address '/btstadmin/users/login' was not found on this server." So I thought it was incorrect. Could the issue be with cache when I log out?

Comment: I have marked this correct as it is the direct answer to the question. The odd behaviour afterwards was solved by disabling the cache

Answer (score 1):

This issue I was seeing was the cause of the cache holding some details and then conflicting. I solved by

```
public function beforeRender() {
    $this->response->disableCache();
}
```